# Is it possible to create apk during runtime?

Tags: android, runtime, apk

Can someone tell me if it's possible to create an apk file during runtime?

I'll explain:

I want to create a deskop program (not android app) that can create apk (android apps) when I run it

it will be like:

1. start the program
2. set application parameters (number of buttons in the menu, links, images, etc..)
3. press create
4. install the apk file on the phone

hope you understand ^^"
and thx for any help (:

Comment: This is almost exactly what Eclipse does. So, yes, it's possible.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, number 1 and 2 is up to you. 3 and 4 requires the Android sdk. Which is public available and we'll documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it is possible. Easier way to do it is by using ant:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html#AntReference

Comment: Have you search documentation about it?